# composed_of & fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

So I have read & re-read the Stephen Chu article on the topic (http://www.stephenchu.com/2008/05/rails-composedof-validation.html), however I am just not having any luck.

Per the example on provided in the money gem documentation money.rubyforge .org

**Model**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :amount,
    :class_name => "Money",
    :mapping => [%w(cents cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
    :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) }
end
```

**Nice skinny controller**

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
    ...
  end
end
```

**View (HAML)**

```
- form_for @payment do |p|
  - p.fields_for :amount, @payment.amount do |a|
    = a.label :cents
    = a.text_field :cents
    = a.label :currency
    = a.text_field :currency, :value => :usd
```

The error I receive is:
undefined method `cents' for {"cents"=>"6.66", "currency"=>"usd"}:HashWithIndifferentAccess

The 'amount' hash is being passed into composed_of as 'cents', but according to the article, it should use the attributes of 'amount' in params from the form.  I'm just really stuck :/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misunderstood your question before. Yes, in your forms you need to reference `amount` this way:

```
- form_for @payment do |p|
   = a.label :dollars
   = a.text_field :amount
   = a.label :currency
   = a.text_field :currency, :value => :usd
```